# PHP Apache container continuously opens /proc/*/fd handles

Tags: linux, apache-http-server, php, docker

**TL:DR:** PHP/Apache in docker is continuously creating 'files' in `/proc/*/fd/` eventually making the site unusable.

We are running a PHP app in docker (`php:5.6-apache`). We deployed this stack to production a few weeks ago. After a few days costumers had problems accessing the site, which was caused by random 403 errors for various files, like javascript, image, etc.
As far as I can tell this was caused by this error

```
[core:crit] [pid 17] (24)Too many open files: AH00529: /var/www/.htaccess pcfg_openfile: unable to check htaccess file, ensure it is readable and that '/var/www/' is executable
```

So I went and checked what files where opened by the Apache processes. `lsof -a -p 15` output:

```
apache2  15 www-data   35   unknown                      /proc/15/fd/35 (readlink: Permission denied)
apache2  15 www-data   37   unknown                      /proc/15/fd/37 (readlink: Permission denied)
apache2  15 www-data   38   unknown                      /proc/15/fd/38 (readlink: Permission denied)
```

The fd number increments continuously when the website is accessed, until eventually it reaches the open file limit.

**EDIT:**
The reason for `(readlink: Permission denied)` was a [docker security feature](https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/136690/how-can-i-substitute-lsof-inside-a-docker-native-not-lxc-based), so all those handles are actually open TCP sockets.

```
apache2  15 www-data  198u     sock    0,8      0t0 794575 protocol: TCP
apache2  15 www-data  200u     sock    0,8      0t0 795679 protocol: TCP
apache2  15 www-data  201u     sock    0,8      0t0 795681 protocol: TCP
```

However netstat lists no unusual open connections. `netstat -a` output:

```
Active Internet connections (servers and established)
Proto Recv-Q Send-Q Local Address           Foreign Address         State
tcp        0      0 127.0.0.11:42045        0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
tcp        0      0 0.0.0.0:80              0.0.0.0:*               LISTEN
udp        0      0 127.0.0.11:59658        0.0.0.0:*
Active UNIX domain sockets (servers and established)
Proto RefCnt Flags       Type       State         I-Node   Path
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Turns out we had the `xdebug` extension installed which doesn't seem to close its sockets correctly.

```
socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, IPPROTO_IP) = 306
20    fcntl(306, F_SETFL, O_RDONLY|O_NONBLOCK) = 0
20    connect(306, {sa_family=AF_INET, sin_port=htons(9000), sin_addr=inet_addr("0.0.0.0")}, 16) = -1 EINPROGRESS (Operation now in progress)
20    select(307, [306], [306], [306], {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=200000}) = 2 (in [306], out [306], left {tv_sec=0, tv_usec=199998})
20    getpeername(306, 0x7ffe1d6453f0, [16]) = -1 ENOTCONN (Transport endpoint is not connected)20
```